# How to synchronize IndexedDB with MySQL uploading a specific table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, synchronization, service-worker, indexeddb

I am developping a offline web app with NodeJS. I managed to store the data I wanted to a IndexedDB database with Service Workers. But I can't synchronize them with my MySQL remote server. I was wondering what was the most feasible solution ?
I tried implement this solution of a tutorial in my app but  without success. This is the link of the tutorial:https://codeforgeek.com/sync-app-mysql-indexeddb/

Comment: The tutorial sounds like a good approach, and an answer here (if your question wouldn't be too broad) would probably look quite similar. We cannot really tell you why it failed for you, as we neither know what you did with that tutorial code, nor how your code looks. We also cannot tell you what the most feasible other solution would be, as we do not know your code, your system setup, your requirements and your personal preferences to make a feasibility-ranking amongst all possible options you might have. Maybe add a specific problem you encounted, e.g. some code + an error message.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The problem is the node server is never launched.